# How to extract flutter/dart parse tree?

Tags: dart, flutter

how to extract all the relations between classes from a flutter file?

for example, in the below code, The desired output should be

1- I have widget  RotationTransition

2- RotationTransition has one child of type Stack

3- Stack has children (Positioned, Center)

4- Positioned has a child of type FlutterLogo

5- Center has one child of type FlutterLogo

(It would be better if it's represented in tree form :D) any ideas How can I get such output?

```
RotationTransition(
        turns: animation,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(
                'Click me!',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dart DevTools. It provides all the widget tree like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use dart tools if you are using VSCode [image]
click on this icon to open dart
and than this will open

[image]

here all the widgets will be shown in tree form with there details too